# Clicking on product color triggers change in all products

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs

I want to show the product's **special price** in the **catalog** but I am getting an **error** when there is **more than one product** with a **discount**. One color product's click triggers a change in all catalog.

I changed the condition on the file:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

It in order to show the special price on catalog product, like this:

```
<?php if (!$block->isProductList() && $block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
```

to

```
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
```

On page load, this is the current view:

[image: Page load]

If I click in a color with a discount (the white color on the first product), it triggers changes on the second one, like this:

[image: The second product changes when I click the first one too]

I am struggled to find where I need to change to fix this problem. Any idea will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem. I changed the `_UpdatePrice()` function from:

```
if (typeof result != 'undefined' && result.oldPrice.amount !== result.finalPrice.amount) {
    $(this.options.slyOldPriceSelector).show();
} else {
    $(this.options.slyOldPriceSelector).hide();
}
```

to:

```js
if (typeof result != 'undefined' && result.oldPrice.amount !== result.finalPrice.amount) {
    $product.find(this.options.slyOldPriceSelector).show();
} else {
    $product.find(this.options.slyOldPriceSelector).hide();
}
```

The previous code was looking for the `.sly-old-price` selector, finding more than one match causing the change in all products. Narrowing the search to the product's container solves the problem.

Hope it helps.